# extract per example datetime from IoT devices without command

Tags: sockets, iot

Good morning,
i need create a project for university about iot, that need sends data from machine to api, and i did some research about it.

But i still confused, because how i send data from machine to api?

I need creat socket program which connect pc(server) to machine that receive their data for after send to api?

I can get data from machine just connecting to her? because i create some socket's program's and i just write data and send, and i want like extract per example datetime from her without command.

Comment: What is "her"? The iot devices? What program do you have so far?

Comment: when i said her i'm talking about machine, for i extract data using program. This moment i have one simple api with crud and socket program that receive data from phone/computer but just what i write in console.

Comment: Okay, what's wrong with that? Clearly you need sockets or an API. Or use MQTT (which is more commonly used in iot factories)

Comment: I just want to know if my thought about send data from machine to api is correct.

Comment: and does websockets interesting for me?

Comment: IoT typically doesn't use web technologies. Like I said, MQTT is one of the most commonly used protocols